# Viewing Apache solr logs on windows

Tags: apache, drupal, solr, drupal-views

I have drupal based site with solr integration. My localhost is on windows and the live site on Linux.

How do I enable and view solr logging for both setups? I can see a log folder in my localhost but its empty.

Just to elaborate, solr search etc works great in both setups. However I built a solr view that works perfectly on local but gives less accurate results on live. So I wanted to see the final solr  queries being built to see the source of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

While starting the Solr instance pass the following parameter to enable Solr logging to file.

`-Djava.util.logging.config.file=etc/logging.properties`

Then modify your `/example/etc/logging.properties` inside you Solr instance to customize your logging pattern.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on the process for the windows setup of solr . This seems to be for the linux.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Solr` Version: `Apache Solr 8.9.0`

You could use the Solr Administration User Interface

Go to `Solr Admin UI` and click the link for "`Logging`".

Then you will see log info.

Selecting the `Level` link on the left, you see the hierarchy of classpaths and classnames for your instance.